# Let $u_n$ be a positive and decreasing sequence of real numbers such that $\sum u_n$ converges. Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}nu_n= 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u_n$ be a positive and decreasing sequence of real numbers such that $\sum u_n$ converges. Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}nu_n= 0$.

**My Attempt:** Since $\sum u_n$ is convergent we know that the sequence $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nu_i $ is convergent and in particular given $\epsilon/2>0$ there exists $n\geq m\geq N$ such that $$|u_{m+1}+u_{m+2}+...+u_n|<\epsilon/2.$$ Since $\{u_n\}$ is decreasing we have that $$(n-m)u_n<|u_{m+1}+u_{m+2}+...+u_n|<\epsilon/2.$$ For $m=N$ we have that $$(n-N)u_n<\epsilon/2.$$Now we know that $u_n\to 0$ and so for $n\geq N'$ $$u_n<\epsilon/2N.$$ Thus for $n\geq \max\{N,N'\}$ we have that $$nu_n<\epsilon/2+Nu_N<\epsilon.$$ This shows that $nu_n\to 0.$

Is this argument correct? I am asking this because the solution in the book is quite different from mine.

Comment: no ,m increases with $\epsilon$  so unclear that their product is small

Comment: @StuartMN is the proof now correct?

Comment: Yes ,the proof is now correct . Good job !

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to explain that last part better. How you get from

- $(n-m)u_n<\frac\epsilon2$
- $u_n<\frac\epsilon2$

to

$$nu_n\to 0$$

is unclear.

Comment: Does the edit make sense?

Comment: @SuperMario Well now I see what you did, but it also highlights where your argument fails. Sure, you have proven that $nu_n<\frac{m+1}{2}\epsilon$, but that doesn't prove yet that $nu_n\to 0$, since you have no bound on the value of $m$.

Comment: $ m $ can be fixed to $ N $ and my answer does the rest.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier True, but the answer currently does not fix $m$, so you can hardly call the proof "perfect", can you?

Comment: But you really need to write "there exists N such that for all..."

Comment: I was going to fix $m$ to $N$, I should have done that...Thanks for your feedback though!

Comment: @SuperMario I suggest you do that and then leave a comment here - I can comment on the edited proof again.

Comment: I have made the edit.

Comment: @SuperMario Looks... OK now. Not perfect, it's still a little hand wavy, but fair enough. You'd get most points if I were grading the test.

Comment: You'd get all points but one if I was grading it, and I told you why already.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is $ u_n\leq \frac {\epsilon}{2m} $. Otherwise it is perfect,  although I would recommend that you take my edit in consideration. Edit if that was unclear: and of course,  fix $ m $ first!

Comment: That's not just an edit and the proof is not perfect. The proof is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to finish your proof but there are much cleaner ways of doing this. 
So given $\epsilon>0$ you found an integer $N$ such that for all $n\geq m\geq N$, 
$$|u_{m+1}+\cdots+u_{n}|<\epsilon/2$$
Also, since $u_n$ is decreasing,
$$nu_n\leq |u_{m+1}+\cdots+u_{n}|+mu_n.$$
Fix $m$. Now since $u_n\to 0$, there is an $N'$ such that for all $n\geq N'$,
$$u_n<\epsilon/(2m).$$
Letting $M=\max(N,N')$ we see that for all $n\geq M$
$$nu_n\leq|u_{m+1}+\cdots+u_{n}|+mu_n<\epsilon,$$
as desired.

---

**Easier Way**

Suppose $nu_n\not\to 0$. WLOG, suppose $nu_n\to a>0$ then there is $N$ such that for $n\ge N$, $nu_n > a/2$ (fill in the details here). So $u_n > a/2n$ for $n\geq N$ and hence
$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty u_n\geq\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{a}{2n}=\frac{a}{2}\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty.$$ 
which is the desired conclusion.

Comment: Again,  you want epsilon over 2m...